# Why does compiled .exe from python script fail to connect to remote ms access database? [HY024]

Tags: python, ms-access, pyinstaller, pyodbc

I'm attempting to connect to an Access .mdb database with Python pyodbc.  I connect to a local database, and this works fine.  The database contains linked tables to a back end .mdb on a network drive.  I receive this error when attempting to select from the linked table:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY024', "[HY024] [Microsoft] [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 'U:\OFFICE\GIS\accessdatabase.mdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. (-1023) (SQLExecDirectW)")

The path name is correct, and the linked tables work fine if I go into my local database and open them.  The python program never mentions the network database or it's path at all, it only connects to the local database.

The python script works fine.  I'm only getting the error when running the compiled .exe generated by Pyinstaller.  Also, a coworker can compile on Windows 10 and his .exe works fine.  But it has to compile on Windows 7 to produce an .exe that works on Windows 7.

Windows 7.

```
conn_str = (
            r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};'
            r'Uid=Admin;Pwd=;'
            r'DBQ=' + self.path
            )
```

Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Are you running the compiled exe while logged in under your normal user account (so you have drive letters mapped as expected)?

Comment: I am.  However while trying to figure out the issue, I have noticed that if I open command prompt as administrator and call NET USE, the network drives are unavailable.  I found this and think the problem is related:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/937624/programs-may-be-unable-to-access-some-network-locations-after-you-turn

Comment: Try using forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an answer exactly, or more of a work around, but I got it to work by re-linking the remote database tables using '\server\name\path' style paths in the local database, instead of 'U:\path' style ones.  Apparently the compiled program was trying to run as administrator for some reason, and in command window the mapped drives were unavailable when running as administrator.  Figured I would share in case anyone else has a similar issue.